¿Como mostrar en una sola consulta las sumas de un campo según una condición y fecha de hoy,. Access?
Access
tengo una  tabla con los siguientes campos
tabla_caja
id,monto,fecha,tipo
monto tipo moneda
fecha tipo fecha
tipo text
quiero hacer una consulta con dos campos
sume los montos según el tipo(existen 2 tipos) y fecha(hoy)
y el resultado sea algo así
entradas hoy |salidas hoy
150         |          200
Gracias de antemano!!
